# What does S/W stand for in printer models?

Tags: printing, printer, laser-printer

I am seeing this abbreviation in some printer model names. Does it mean "**software**" or "**stacker/wireless**" or something else? Or,is it an abbreviation for a term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an abbreviation in German of **schwarz/weiß** which stands for **black/white**.